# Soap client from WSDL: add ws-security header

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, wcf-data-services

In c# console project i have added a service reference from wsdl.

In the app config i have the following xml code:

```
<bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding name="verificaValiditaPatenteSoap11" />
     </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://myurl.com/services/myservice"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="xxxxxxxx"
            contract="xxxxxx" name="xxxxxx" />
</client>
```

When i see the output of the request i have no wsse header.
I need in the message the following header in the request. How can i achieve this? How can i add the ws-security? There is any tutorial?

```
<soapenv:Header><wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-91C0647D2779DF588C14621957892417"><wsse:Username>MyUsername</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">MyPassword</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
```

Answer (score -3):

For some pratical guidance, you should take a look at Scott Hanselman's blog, here is a post about WS-Security:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BreakingAllTheRulesWithWCF.aspx

And there is this Microsoft patterns & practies addressing WS-Security fundamentals: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650862.aspx

Anyway, you can start including security transport in your service adding this to your coniguration file:

```
<binding name="verificaValiditaPatenteSoap11">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
</binding>
```

So you will be able to find the WS-Security headers.

Hope it helps